# jpCarousel positioning wrong

Tags: css-position, typo3, jcarousel

i installed the extension jpCarousel in Typo3 and want to add a slideshow. I changed nothing at the template css file of jpCarousel, but the container is not in the same position like the red div, which also is a div of the extension...

can anyone help me, and tell how i can adjust the galerie to the red div?
thanks!

http://preview-list.lmenges.de/index.php?id=auto

greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Optimize **your** CSS, for an example `width` of `#content_left` causes moving content of right column down. Use some inspector in your browser to make it correctly, for now you have there a quite big mess.

Comment: thx for your reply! but the container of the plugin fits right into the content_right div. but the div of the slideshow is not within the container? why=